# Why can't I run #[test]s defined in main()?

Tags: unit-testing, rust

I'm learning Rust and I want to test a simple function inside main.rs as:

```
fn main() {
    fn adder(n: u64, m:u64) -> u64 {
        assert!(n != 0 && m !=0);
        n + m
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_gcd(){
        assert_eq!(adder(1, 10), 11);
        assert_eq!(adder(100, 33), 133);
    }
    println!("{}", adder(3, 4));
    println!("The END");
}
```

When I run `cargo test` no test are found and this warning shows up:

```
warning: cannot test inner items
 --> src\main.rs:7:5
  |
7 |     #[test]
  |     ^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: `#[warn(unnameable_test_items)]` on by default
  = note: this warning originates in the attribute macro `test` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

warning: `rust_prueba` (bin "rust_prueba" test) generated 1 warning
    Finished test [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.58s
     Running unittests src\main.rs (target\debug\deps\rust_prueba-e1ba8a7bcfb64cfc.exe)

running 0 tests

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.00s
```

But, if I define both the adder function and the test function **outside** the main function, it works:

```
fn main() {
    println!("{}", adder(3, 4));
    println!("The END");
}

fn adder(n: u64, m:u64) -> u64 {
    assert!(n != 0 && m !=0);
    n + m
}

#[test]
fn test_gcd(){
    assert_eq!(adder(1, 10), 11);
    assert_eq!(adder(100, 33), 133);
}
```

`cargo test`:

```
running 1 test
test test_gcd ... ok

test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.00s
```

Why didn't my first try work?

Comment: Unrelated nitpick: Please wrap your tests in `#[cfg(test)]`, [as shown here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-01-writing-tests.html). Otherwise they will be compiled into the release binary.

Comment: @Finomnis Not true. [Tests are always `#[cfg(test)]`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/a2318651d4d2c6280a5047544cbf4180119ba966/compiler/rustc_builtin_macros/src/test.rs#L82-L84). It is a good practice to use `#[cfg(test)]` **on their module**, to prevent the cost of type-checking it etc., and even better to extract it to a file because then it doesn't even need to be parsed.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Ha! I learned something today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nested tests are not possible.

There was a [request to add that](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/36629), but the outcome was that this is impossible to implement:

> The problem with this is that the test harness needs to access the inner functions, which it can't do because you can't name them.

The best solution, in my opinion, would be to restructure your code so that the method you want to test isn't nested anymore.